# Sql server Datetime comparison is taking time to execute

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, datetime, comparison

I have a query in SQL Server2005, where 2 date fields are compared. If I dont include time and use only date part for comparison then the query runs fast(in milliseconds). However, I need to compare the time also along with Date part. If I include time part the query runs very slow and finally its returning connection time out error.

```
 `((startdate1 >= @startdate2 and enddate1 <= @enddate2) or
(startdate1 <= @startdate2 and enddate1 >= @startdate2 and enddate1 <= @enddate2 ) or
(startdate1 >= @startdate2 and startdate1 < @enddate2 and enddate1 > @enddate2) or
(startdate1 < @startdate2 and enddate1 > @enddate2))`
```

This part of the query is taking a lot of time to execute. However, If I change the query to below format, query runs very fast.

```
    ((cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),startdate1,101) as datetime) >= cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@startdate2,101) as datetime)      
AND cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),enddate1,101) as datetime)<=  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@enddate2,101) as datetime) ) OR     

(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),startdate1,101) as datetime) <=  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@startdate2,101) as datetime)      
AND ((cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),enddate1,101) as datetime) >= cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@startdate2,101) as datetime) )     
AND (cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),enddate1,101) as datetime) <=  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@enddate2,101) as datetime)  ))) OR 

(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),startdate1,101) as datetime) >=  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@startdate2,101) as datetime)  and     
((cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),startdate1,101) as datetime) < cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@enddate2,101) as datetime) ) AND     
(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),enddate1,101) as datetime) >  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@enddate2,101) as datetime)  ))) OR     

(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),startdate1,101) as datetime) <  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@startdate2,101) as datetime)  and     
cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),enddate1,101) as datetime) >  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@enddate2,101) as datetime) ))
```

Please suggest me some idea on this. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: That... doesn't make sense. All of those conversions against columns should rule out any potential index usage, whereas the first query should be able to use indexes (if they exist). Do you have any useful indexes on these columns?

Comment: Wrong query plan cached for first case? Run 'update statistics on yourtable with fullscan' (this should flush cache and recompute stats) and try again.

Comment: How to run 'update statistics on yourtable with fullscan'

Comment: This query is taking time in the stored proc but when I executed this as a seperate query then it took fraction of second only. Any idea why its taking time only in stored procedure and run fast as an independent query

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DateDiff` function?

Comment: Yes.. Tried..this is also taking time to execute. Code snippet is :          ((datediff(mm,@startdate2,startdate1)>=0  and datediff(mm,@enddate2,enddate1)<=0) or
(datediff(mm,@startdate2,startdate1)<=0  and datediff(mm,@startdate2,enddate1)>=0  and datediff(mm,@enddate2,enddate1)<=0) or
(datediff(mm,@startdate2,startdate1)>=0  and datediff(mm,@enddate2,startdate1)< 0  and datediff(mm,@enddate2,enddate1)>0) or
(datediff(mm,@startdate2,startdate1)<0  and datediff(mm,@enddate2,enddate1)>0))

Comment: Execution time is more than 20 mins for just 10 records in table

Comment: This doesn't make sense, what's the type you defined those variables?could you paste more codes in your procedure